# Arduino SE and cross-posts: How to do community moderation?

Tags: discussion, community-moderators, flagging

I flagged a cross-post for moderator attention and the flag was declined with "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

What would be the right way to handle it?

I acted based on this SO Meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255649/is-so-se-crosspost-accepted

Answer (score 1):

In this instance I took the decision that the post was at home here and the post on the other site should be closed.

Just because a post exists on more than one site it doesn't always follow that this site should have the question closed.

Comment: ok, but does it mean that the flag is automatically declined?

Comment: No, it means I declined it.

Comment: why did you decline it?

Comment: For the reasons I stated in my answer. I felt the one on ASE should be the one to stay since it was on topic here.